# Dead Man's Hand and Deathstreaks

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

What does Dead Man's Hand do and how does it work? Does it count to your deaths if you fail to get a kill using it? or even if you kill does it still count to your deaths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dead Man's Hand has similar effect to Last Stand or Second Chance from previous CoD games (when you receive damage that is incompatible with life, you fall and pull out a pistol), however you get C4 planted on yourself, and you can detonate it with a detonator (in similar way as detonating C4s you plant) to blast yourself.